# Trying To Change Color Of An Entire Row Based On Found Text In One Google Sheets Cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I found some very simple Apps Script code online that scans for a set value (MONDAY) in a Google sheets cell and then changes the color of the cell if it finds a match.

I am trying to modify the code to change color of the entire row if it finds a match, not just the individual cell.

I used the logger to determine that I am trying to pass setBackgroundRGB a number instead of a range. I just can't figure out how to get the range of the entire row instead of just the cell.

```
function rowColorChanger() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var findString = 'MONDAY';
  var textFinder = sheet.createTextFinder(findString);
  var items = textFinder.findAll();
  items.forEach(cell=>{
    var row = cell.getRow();          //IF YOU REMOVE THIS LINE IT BREAKS AND I DON'T UNDERSTAND WHY
    var col = cell.getColumn();       //IF YOU REMOVE THIS LINE IT BREAKS AND I DON'T UNDERSTAND WHY
    Logger.log(row);                  //THIS RETURNS A NUMERICAL VALUE IN THE LOG
    Logger.log(col);                  //THIS RETURNS A NUMERICAL VALUE IN THE LOG
    Logger.log(cell);                 //THIS LOGS AS: "Range"
    cell.setBackgroundRGB(255,255,0); //THIS WORKS BUT ONLY CHANGES THE INDIVIDUAL CELL
    row.setBackgroundRGB(255,255,0);  //THIS DOES NOT WORK (THIS IS MY ATTEMPT TO CHANGE THE ROW)
  })
}
```

I feel like there has to be some really simple change that I am missing. I've tried many, many different things, and other code, but none of what I try works.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

```
    var row = cell.getRow();
    row.setBackgroundRGB(255,255,0);
```

The code does not work because the variable `row` holds an integer while `setBackgroundRGB()` is a `Range` method. Use `Sheet.getRange()`, like this:

```
  const columnEnd = sheet.getLastColumn();
    // ...
    const row = cell.getRow();
    cell.getSheet().getRange(row, 1, 1, columnEnd).setBackgroundRGB(255, 255, 0);
```

The whole thing would probably be easier to implement with a [conditional formatting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413) custom formula rule that changes cell fill colors dynamically rather than a script that only changes cell fill colors when you run it.

Comment: The OP defines `sheet` as `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()`, but `getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)` is a "Sheet" method (not a "Spreadsheet" method).  Add `const cellSheet =  cell.getSheet()` and change the last line to `cellSheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, columnEnd).setBackgroundRGB(255, 255, 0)`.

Comment: Thanks. Edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Completely agree with doubleunary. You can set a simple formula that will be applied to each cell of the range that's being formatted. And you can "play" with anchoring (this simbol -> $) to apply that to an entire row or column.
The formula can return true or false. But it also works with numbers, 0 is false and >1 is true. So you can set a MATCH (that will return the number of column where MONDAY is (or not)

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't it be more efficient  to create the conditional format within the script?

Comment: Mmm, I don't know. Since Barton may had not known about this tool I thought it was interesting for him to know it. Create a conditional formatting this way can take how much?, 30 seconds each condition?, but writing a whole script (however it may be simple) at least for me takes a lot longer and is much more fallible. Even with conditional formatting you're actually seeing the result within each thing you modify of a formula. (Obviously @doubleunary was a great response and the most direct to Barton's question!!)

Comment: Yeah. fair point.